# Push to wake a backgrounded iOS 8 app does not get any data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications, ios8

There's a new feature in iOS 8: using a push notification to wake an app, which also lets the app refresh data in the background. How do I use this feature?

The push notification arrives with a value of 1 for the key 'content-available'. However, no data is received if the app is not already running in background. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things here,

1.U need to check Remote Notification on under Background mode of the target in Capabilities section.

2.U need to implement below method,

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler